# Handling request in django view: accessing the body

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I' trying a modify my database on a condition based on a body object from the request.

here is my fetch function:

```
 document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const magazinOption = e.target.value;
    const mag_url = "{% url 'my-subscriptions' %}";
    if (magazinOption === 'digital') {
        fetch(mag_url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'magazine': 'digital'
            })
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Choix de magazin:', paper_magazine );
        });
    }
});
```

Then in my view file i have this.

```
    def post(self, request):
    ...
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(request_body)
    print('body:', request_body['magazine'])
    print('body to string:', str(request_body['magazine']))
    if str(request_body['magazine']) == 'digital':
        user.paper_magazine = False
        user.save()
```

And in my terminal this is what i see:

```
04/Jul/2021 08:08:18] "GET /static/src/images/earth.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 3503
{'magazine': 'digital'}
body: digital
body to string: digital
Internal Server Error: /client-profile-new/subscriptions/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.pyenv/versions/jaenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.pyenv/versions/jaenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view apps.front.views.profile.NewProfileSubscriptionsView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[04/Jul/2021 08:08:25] "POST /client-profile-new/subscriptions/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73892
```

What am i missing ? Why can't i access the body object's value?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the processing of the body, but every view needs to return a HTTP response, so you should return a response, for example with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def post(self, request):
    # …
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request_body['magazine'] == 'digital':
        user.paper_magazine = False
        user.save()
    #  return a response ↓
    return HttpResponse('hi')
```

Comment: This works too. i had JsonResponse already imported so i went for that option. Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but you are missing something.

your view must return a `HttpResponse` object, but it returns `None`.

It can be `redirect`, `HttpResponse`, `JsonResponse` or ...

in your case:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def post(self, request):
    # ...
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(request_body)
    print('body:', request_body['magazine'])
    print('body to string:', str(request_body['magazine']))
    if str(request_body['magazine']) == 'digital':
        user.paper_magazine = False
        user.save()
    
    # returning a json response for example
    return JsonResponse(
        data={"message": "ok"},
        status=200,
    )
```

Comment: glad to hear that. @RomainBOBOE